# YouTube API results to Mysql

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm running a query against the you tube api using the sdk to retrieve a list of videos about a given subject.

Using the examples provided, I can get the results to output to the console but I'd like them to be inserted into a mysql database. The code im using is:

```
$results = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $term,
  'maxResults' => 50,
  'order' => "date",
  'regionCode' => "GB",
));
$videos = '';
$channels = '';
foreach ($results['items'] as $searchResult) {
    echo $results;
    echo $searchresults;
    $query = "insert into data(VideoId,Title)values "
        . "($searchResult->videoId,"
        . "$searchResult->title)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

But this returns an error:

> "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Google_Service_YouTube_SearchListResponse could not be converted to string ".

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the library code, look into the `/Service/YouTube.php` file to find out the type of the data returned.

For your example, I looked for the method `listSearch` in that file. It returns a `Google_Service_YouTube_SearchListResponse`. Looking for that class (in the same file), we can see that the items type is `Google_Service_YouTube_SearchResult` and you should get it with:

```
$items = $results->getItems();
```

To get the ID and title you should do:

```
$videoId = $searchResult->getId()->getVideoId();
$videoTitle = $searchResult->getSnippet()->getTitle();
```